# How to add pinch to zoom to horizontal scrollView?

Tags: swift, uiscrollview

I have a horizontal scrollView

```
@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView! 

override func viewDidLoad() {

    for image in imageArray {
       let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
       scrollView.addSubview(imageView)
       imageViews.append(imageView)
    }

}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {


    for (index,imageView) in imageViews.enumerate() {
        imageView.frame = CGRectMake(CGFloat(index)*scrollView.frame.size.width, 0, scrollView.frame.size.width, scrollView.frame.size.height)
    }

    let imageArrayCount = CGFloat(imageArray.count)

    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width *  imageArrayCount, scrollView.frame.size.height)

}
```

How to modify it in order to make method `viewForZoomingInScrollView(scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView?` work ? Description of method says, that I need view, which will be zoomed, but I don't understand how to embed new views in scrollview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `viewForZoomingInScrollView(_:)` is supposed to return **one** `UIView` that will be used to zoom (the scale of this view will be changed). So you have to put all your images into one view and add the view to the scroll view.

This is what you have to do to make zooming work:

Add a property for the container view:

```
class YourViewControllerClass: UIViewController {
    let imagesContainerView = UIView()
    ...
}
```

Add all your image views to this container view and add the container view to your scroll view:

```
scrollView.addSubview(imagesContainerView)
view.addSubview(scrollView)

for image in imageArray {
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
    imagesContainerView.addSubview(imageView)
    imageViews.append(imageView)
}
```

After you set the `contentSize` for the scroll view, set the container view's frame accordingly:

```
imagesContainerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, scrollView.contentSize.width, scrollView.contentSize.height)
```

Enable zooming by setting max and min zoom scale on the scroll view and set the delegate:

```
scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 5.0
scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1
scrollView.delegate = self
```

Implement the delegate method:

```
func viewForZoomingInScrollView(scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
    return imagesContainerView
}
```

Comment: Thats a great answer! Thank you very much!